# Contradicting results on the convergence of a series involving the Gregory's coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Consider the series :
$$I(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}|G_{m+1}|\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^{j}\binom{m}{j}\cos(2\pi (j+1)x)$$
Where $|G_{m+1}|$ are the absolute [Gregory's coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients#:%7E:text=Gregory%20coefficients%20are%20alternating%20G,in%20the%20numerical%20integration%20context.) ($|G_{m+1}|=(-1)^{m}G_{m+1}$). By the binomial theorem, we have :
$$\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^{j}\binom{m}{j}\cos(2\pi (j+1)x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{2\pi i x}(1-e^{2\pi i x})^{m}+e^{-2\pi i x}(1-e^{-2\pi i x})^{m}\right)$$
But since :
$$\frac{-z}{\log(1-z)}=1-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}|G_{m}|z^{m}$$
converges in the unit disk, the series $I(x)$ given above converges for $|1-e^{2\pi i x}|<1$. Explicitly, this is given by :
$$I(x)=\frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{2\pi x}-\frac{1}{2}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\left(|1-e^{2\pi i x}|<1\right)$$
However, using the Taylor expansion :
$$\cos(2\pi x(j+1))=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k)!}(2\pi x)^{2k}(j+1)^{2k}$$
And the [globally convergent series for the Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Globally_convergent_series)  :
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}+\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}|G_{m+1}|\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^{j}\binom{m}{j}(j+1)^{-s}\;\;\;s\in \mathbb{C}/{1}$$
we have :
$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}|G_{m+1}|\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^{j}\binom{m}{j}\cos(2\pi (j+1)x)$$$$=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}|G_{m+1}|\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^{j}\binom{m}{j}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k)!}(2\pi x)^{2k}(j+1)^{2k}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k+1)!}(2\pi x)^{2k}=\frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{2\pi x}-\frac{1}{2}\;\;\;\;\;\left(x\in \mathbb{R}\right)$$
where we used :
$$\zeta(-2k)=0\;\;\;\;(k=1,2,3...)\;\;\;\;\;\;\zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$$
The two approaches give different regions of convergence ! Where did i go wrong ?

Comment: reversing the order of summation, and using $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}|G_{m+1}|\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^{j}\binom{m}{j}(j+1)^{2k}=\zeta(-2k)+\frac{1}{2k+1}$, the result follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A triple series

$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}|G_{m+1}|\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^{j}\binom{m}{j}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k)!}(2\pi x)^{2k}(j+1)^{2k}$$

can fail to [converge absolutely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence).  For instance, for $x=1/2$, when
$$\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^{j}\binom{m}{j}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k)!}(2\pi x)^{2k}(j+1)^{2k}=$$
$$\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^{j}\binom{m}{j}\cos (2\pi(j+1)x)=$$
$$\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^{j}\binom{m}{j}(-1)^{j+1}=
-2^m.$$ So we may be not allowed to change the order of its summation.
Thus a convergence of the interchanged series can fail to imply a convergence of the initial series.